# Selectively remove subfields from a CSV file in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a CSV file `my.csv`, in which fields are separated by `;`. Each field contains arbitrary number (sometimes zero) of subfields separated by `|`, like this:

```
aa5|xb1;xc3;ba7|cx2|xx3|da2;ed1
xa2|bx9;ab5;;af2|xb5
xb7;xa6|fc5;fd6|xb5;xc3|ax9
df3;ab5|xc7|de2;da5;ax2|xd8|bb1
```

I would like to remove all sub-fields (with corresponding `|`'s) that start from everything but `x`, i.e. get output like this:

```
xb1;xc3;xx3;
xa2;;;xb5
xb7;xa6;xb5;xc3
;xc7;;xd8
```

Now I am doing this in multiple steps with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^[^;x]*;/;/g' my.csv #In 1st fields without x.
sed -i 's/;[^;x]*;/;;/g' my.csv #In middle field without x.
sed -i 's/;[^;x]*$/;/g' my.csv #In last field without x.
sed -i 's/^[^;x][^;]*|x/x/g' my.csv #In 1st fields with x. before x.
sed -i 's/;[^;x][^;]*|x/;x/g' my.csv #In non-1st fields with x. before x.
sed -i 's/|[^x][^;]*//g' my.csv #In fields with x. after x.
```

Is there a way to do it one line or at least more simple? I got stuck on the problem how to match "line beginning OR ';'".

In my case it is guaranteed that there is no more than one subfield starting with `x`. In theory, however, it would be also useful how to solve the problem if it is not the case (e.g., convert field `ab1|xa2|bc3|xd4|ex5` to `xa2|xd4`).

Comment: @anubhava I want to keep only subfields starting with `x`

Comment: @anubhava Have you read the question?

Comment: Why do the `;` in the output seem to be random

Comment: The `;` are not random. They are the delimiters. However, there are some empty field, so we see several delimiters one straight after another

Comment: @Roman Yeah noticed after i commented, posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed ':;s/\(^\||\|;\)[^x;|][^;|]*/\1/;t;s/|//g' file
```

Just loops through removing fields that don't begin with x and then removes the bars.

#### Output

```
xb1;xc3;xx3;
xa2;;;xb5
xb7;xa6;xb5;xc3
;xc7;;xd8
```

Comment: This is real wizardry! In order to handle the case with multiple subfields we can add a little bit to it: `sed ':;s/\(^\||\|;\)[^x;|][^;|]*/\1/;t;s/|$//g;;s/|\($\|[^x]\)/\1/g;s/;|/;/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(/(^|\|)[^x][^|]*/, "", $i); sub(/^\|/, "", $i)}} 1' file
xb1;xc3;xx3;
xa2;;;xb5
xb7;xa6;xb5;xc3
;xc7;;xd8
```

This will also convert `ab1|xa2|bc3|xd4|ex5` to `xa2|xd4` i.e. **multiple fields** starting with `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Perl:

```
perl -ple '$_ = join(";", map { join "|", grep /^x/, split /\|/ } split(/;/, $_, -1))'
```

This starts with `split(/;/, $_, -1)`, splitting the line (`$_` at this point) into an array of fields at semicolons. The negative limit parameter makes it so that trailing empty fields (if they exist) are not discarded.

The elements of that array are

1. transformed in the `map` expression, and
2. `join`ed again with semicolons.

The transformation in the `map` expression is

1. `split`ting along `|`,
2. `grep`ping for `/^x/` (i.e., weeding out those that don't match the regex),
3. `join`ing with `|` again.

I believe this structured approach to be more robust than regex wizardry.

**Old code that loses empty fields at the end of a line:**

```
perl -F\; -aple '$_=join(";", map { join("|", grep(/^x/, split(/\|/, $_))) } @F)'
```

This used `-a` for auto-split, which looked nicer but didn't have the fine-grained control over field splitting that was required.

Comment: Very nice! There is, however, one flaw: it loses semicolons at the end of the line, e.g., `xa1;;` becomes `xa1`, thought it must remain unchanged

Comment: @Roman Oh, so it does. `-a` does not work for you, then, but splitting manually allows keeping those empty fields. I edited in a fix for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk -F";" -vOFS=";" '
       {line=sep="";
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            c=split($i,s,"|"); 
            for(j=1;j<=c;j++) 
               if(s[j]~/^x/) {
                   line=line sep s[j];
                   sep=OFS
               }
        } 
        print line}'
```

split each element further for pattern check, combine results in a line, set separator after the first element is set on each line.

Comment: this doesn't preserve the field separators though!

Comment: ...and does not look much simpler